# How do you deploy Global.asax and Global.cs file to WFE

Tags: deployment

I need to deploy the above files to the WFE. Since there are more than 1 WFE in our farm, I am looking for a good method of deploying it to all our WFE as compare to copying it manually.

By making it part of the feature will not help as they will not get deployed to all WFE

Answer (score 1):

The definitive way to deploy that kind of artifact is with a feature, bundled within a solution package.  Why would you deploy your global.asax to only some of your WFE?  You should also compile your .cs to make it a DLL and include it within your solution.

Comment: +1 Definitely need a solution field. Here is a tool that makes WSP files easier: http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/